# Distinct terms for a monolingual dictionary and a bilingual dictionary

Tags: single-word-requests, differences

I am writing a text where I need to address two types of dictionaries *distinctly*;

The first type of dictionary presents words alongside one or more possible definitions, constrained to a single language. The second type is a bilingual/multilingual dictionary where words are presented with their translations.

I feel like monolingual does not automatically infer a dictionary of definitions. Also in general monolingual/bilingual/multilingual feels *excessively* technical and I'd resort to them if the distinction I'm trying to make cannot be conveyed by a simple term or phrase.

A quick Google search shows me https://www.merriam-webster.com/ is the first type of dictionary I'm trying to define while
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-german is the second type.

I would like to know if distinct terms or phrases exist for these two dictionary types so I can clearly phrase which one I'm talking about during my writing.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what the entry on *lexicon* is talking about. Although it can be used to describe a dictionary, especially a Greek one (whether mono- or bi-lingual) it is describing here the set of words you know and saying it usually refers to one language. Thus "I have a lexicon of 20,000 words in English, and one of 2 words in Welsh" rather than just counting the total number of words I know.

Comment: @DavidRobinson you are absolutely right. My question still stands but the confusion is solved now, I edited my question to reflect the change.

Comment: As far as I know, *dictionary* and all its synonyms, such as *glossary*, *vocabulary*, *word book* etc. can be monolingual, bilingual or multilingual so I'm afraid you just have to use these horrible long adjectives!

Comment: Are you asking what a monolingual and a bilingual dictionary are called? Your question is confusing. What is wrong with the words "monolingual" and "bilingual"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am asking if there exists a proper term/phrase for a dictionary where words are presented with their translation on the target language and type of dictionary where words are followed by one or more definitions for possible meanings. I can edit my question to make it more clear. I feel like monolingual and bilingual does not automatically mean the distinction I'm trying to make.

Comment: Yeah, I think you should edit and say ***why*** the terms *monolingual* and/or *bilingual dictionary* do not suit your needs. Bilingual means two languages, but you also mention "multilingual" in the question body.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I tried to clarify as best as I could, please let me know if the question is still confusing.

Comment: ["monolingual dictionary"](https://www.google.com/search?ei=iIPiXNH-C6CG1fAP97elkAY&q=%22monolingual+dictionary%22+&oq=%22monolingual+dictionary%22+&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i67j0l9.5311.11575..13115...0.0..0.98.271.3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30.r0F3RMyfi68) or just plain "dictionary" :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA you're right, plain **dictionary** is apparently synonymous with a _descriptive dictionary_ . I also found an authoritative answer for the second type, thank you for your comments :).

Comment: A monolingual dictionary for Spanish, for example, could be *an all-Spanish dictionary*.

Comment: 'I feel like 'monolingual' does not automatically infer [a] dictionary of definitions.' It doesn't. But 'monolingual dictionary' does.

Answer (score 2):

On A Practical Guide to Lexicography (2003), edited by Piet van Sterkenburg, the first *type* of dictionary is referred as *dictionary*.

> For us, looking for a definition of ‘dictionary’ is looking for a definition of the prototypical dictionary. The prototypical dictionary is the alphabetical monolingual general-purpose dictionary. Its characteristics are the use of one and the same language for both the object and the means of description, the supposed exhaustive nature of the list of described words and the more linguistic than encyclopaedic nature of the knowledge offered. The monolingual general-purpose dictionary . . .
>
> > contains primarily semasiological rather than onomasiological or non-semantic data, gives a description of a standard language rather than restricted or marked language varieties, and serves a pedagogical purpose rather than a critical or scholarly one.
> >     (Geeraerts 1989:293–294)

---

> What makes the monolingual general-purpose dictionary so prototypical? I will continue here on the course set out by Béjoint (2000:40):
>
> > It is the one that every household has, that everyone thinks of first when the word **dictionary** is mentioned, it is the type that is most often bought, most often consulted, the one that plays the most important role in the society that produces it. (Page 3)

The second type of the dictionary is referred as *multilingual* or *translation* dictionary.

> According to Zgusta (1971:294) the basic aim of multilingual or translation dictionaries is ‘to co-ordinate with the lexical units of one language those units of another language which are equivalent in their lexical meaning’. On the microstructural level this function is realised by providing for a lemma in the source language one or more translation equivalents in the target language. (Page 67)

Comment: I think it's important to note that the first type is being referred to as _prototypical_ dictionary (as opposed to _multilingual_ or _translation_ dictionary).

Comment: @Zack I wanted to highlight the second snippet where the author argues 'dictionary' is  generally associated with 'prototypical, monolingual, descriptive' dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A monolingual dictionary is a dictionary with only one language in. A bilingual dictionary is one that has both the words in one language, and their divergent in another.

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking for but seeing how my question text might be misleading I edited it.